# Choosing a group of 6 balls (from a group of 18 balls) such that exactly one color of ball is not chosen at all

Tags: combinatorics

Bob is trying to choose 6 balls from a bucket of 18 balls. The bucket contains 3 balls of each color, and there are 6 colors total. In each set of 3 balls, one of the balls is small, one is medium, and one is large. How many sets of 6 balls can Bob choose, if exactly one color is not chosen at all?

I am thinking about partitioning the problem into cases: 

- One of the balls of the forbidden color is chosen

- Two of the balls of the forbidden color is chosen

- Three of the balls of the forbidden color is chosen

At the end, I would subtract the sum of all these case from the total number of ways you could choose 6 balls from a bucket of 18 balls. Is this correct?

Comment: Are you taking into account that there are three ways to choose the forbidden color?  If so, you're correct, though it seems easier to ask, "How many ways are there to choose $3$ balls from the $6$ permitted ones," and then multiply by $3$.

Comment: 6 ways to pick the excluded color. Now your sample must have 1 of each of the eligible colors, $3^5$ ways to do that, and there are 10 more eligible balls to fill the sample. $6(3^5)(10)$ is a tentative answer but i still feel like I'm over counting.

Comment: Ok maybe I misinterpreted. Is the excluded color fixed?

Comment: @Muselive you have counted every possibilities twice. Choosing the small red ball first, the the medium red ball is the same as choosing the meduim red ball then the small red ball.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have $6$ colors and you need that exactly one is not chosen, then four colors will be chosen once and one color will be chosen twice.

You first choose which color is not there $6\choose1$, then, from the remaining five, which will be chosen twice ${5\choose1}{3\choose2}$. Finally, choose one ball for the remaining colors ${3\choose1}^4$.

Number of possible sets is 
$${6\choose1}{5\choose1}{3\choose2}{3\choose1}^4=7290$$

Answer (score 0):

This is correct if somebody tells you which color is forbidden.  The problem wants you to consider that any color might be the one missing.  You can't just multiply your result by $6$ because it will double count the ones that are missing two colors.  You can use the inclusion-exclusion principle to handle that.